# Dynamic Dimension of UITableViewCell ok, but how hide them if empty?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios8

I have a `UITableView` with 3 prototyped cells (ex. 1st cell: image, 2nd cell: Description, 3. Links,...).

I would like to hide them if for a cell the data from the backend is empty (Ex. if there is no image, hide the first cell). In order to do that, I have override the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` function in this way:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    switch (indexPath.row) {

    case 0:
        if event?.photo_urls.count == 0{
            return 0
        }
        else{
            return 80.0
        }
    case 1:
        if event?.description == ""{
            return 0
        }
        else{
            return 90.0
        }
    default:
        return 100.0
    }
}
```

and hidden the cell by doing

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    switch (indexPath.row) {

    case 0:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PhotoCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

        if event?.photo_urls.count != 0 {
            // ...
        }
        else{
            cell.hidden = true
        }

        return cell

    case 1:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("DesCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
       if event?.description != "" {
            // ...
        }
        else{
            cell.hidden = true
        }

        return cell

    default:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PhotoCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        return cell

    }
}
```

Until here no problem, it works properly!
Now, THE PROBLEM is that I would like to make the cells dynamics according to the cell contents (ex. description height). In order to do that, I have used

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80.0
 }
```

and if I comment the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` the cells are actually dynamics but I can't hide them anymore.

Do you have any suggestion on how to be able to hide the cells if they are empty and apply the automatic dimension according to their content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets say you have dynamic data and you want to show it in tableview  so you need  to create an array of your data  to display.

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
@IBOutlet
var tableView: UITableView
var items: [String] = ["We", "Heart", "nothing" ,"" ,"imageurl", "", "xyz"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    reloadTableAfterSorting()
    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}

func reloadTableAfterSorting(){

for var i = 0; i < self.items.count; i++
   {

    if self.items[i] == ""{
        self.items.removeAtIndex(2)

     }


   }

  self.tableView.reloadData()
 }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
  }
}
```

Comment: please check it if you understand then  accept the answer so it will help me as well @valeC

Comment: thank you again for your solution, but I think I can't apply it in my case because all the cells I have are customised (disposition of the labels, images, one ore more labels, maps...)

Comment: brother you can apply it easily i gave you the way you can  do this  and it will hell you i suggest you  to try this its will help you to understand the flow  or give  me your complete code here i will make it  for you  as you want  plus describe the value you want to display please accept the answer  if it help you

Answer (score 0):

For that i recommend you to sort the array before displaying it in the table view. Hiding the cell is not a good idea and its not good according to Apple recommendations. So you can do one thing except hiding the cell: remove the index from the array. In this way you can always have data to show in table and it will behave properly. So don’t try to hide the cell just pop the index from array.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry I am pretty new in iOS dev: remove the index from which array?

Comment: you are welcome. so don’t have array. is it a static tableview  okay let me write  it  for you  give a mint